# Weird query: "equal slash id" (=/id) gives weird error: 501

Tags: php, apache, http, url, query-string

This is the weirdest problem of my life, and can't even Google it. It's happening on an Apache powered website written in PHP, which uses mod_rewrite (but that's not the issue, I tried removing the .htaccess file, problem still exists).

**If I have a query string that looks exactly or similar to: `=/id` I get an 501 response**:

> **Method Not Implemented**
>
> GET to / not supported.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I never written such error page, never sent an 501 response, don't have the slightest clue where this thing is coming from. Originally I had a long URL giving me a similar error, but I stripped down to this little snippet above. If I remove or change any character, the error's gone.

If that helps: my website is [commentards.net](http://commentards.net), and the original URL was an openid login request which looks like this:

[http://commentards.net/q/user/auth?openid_identifier=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id](http://commentards.net/q/user/auth?openid_identifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid)

from which the query string is:

> ?openid_identifier=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/Fid

Comment: The query string should not contain any ? inside, did you tried with an urlencoded question mark?

Comment: I didn't had problems with other queries. Your right, I used the term in a wrong way, I modified my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the support team, and they said it was **mod_security**, and disabled it for my website. And now it works fine. I should have started with that. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: omg thank you so much for posting what your solution was! i have had a similar issue with a json-encoded GET param where part of a parameter's value was `|id` - i was getting 501 errors and it was driving me nuts! it was modsec!!!

Answer (score -1):

Urlencode your query string parameter(s).

https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
becomes
https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2FFid

http://commentards.net/q/user/auth?openid_identifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2FFid works fine, so HerrSerker  already answered your question.

Comment: What you gave was not ".../o8/id" it was ".../o8/Fid" and that was why it worked. The first one still doesn't work. I tested with firefox, and firefox encodes it automatically. I used http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to decode the URL you gave